# Error "cannot access org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired" al cambiar versiones de Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Estoy tratando de actualizar las versiones de Spring Boot de mi aplicación para eliminar algunas vulnerabilidades de seguridad. Sin embargo, al hacerlo, estoy encontrando el siguiente error al compilar:

cannot access org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
class file for org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired not found

He comprobado que tengo las siguientes dependencias de Spring Boot en mi archivo pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.27</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

¿Por qué no está encontrando la clase Autowired? ¿Hay alguna otra dependencia que deba agregar o alguna configuración adicional que deba hacer para resolver este problema?

Cualquier ayuda sería muy apreciada. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Esas dependencias son las que están escritas en el `pom.xml` de tu proyecto? o las dependencias que te genera `spring-boot`? `spring` es el framework, mientras que `spring-boot` es más una herramienta que te ayuda a crear proyectos que usen el framework pero ahorrandote varias líneas de configuraciones

Comment: Acá un artículo que explica la [diferencia entre spring y spring-boot](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-vs-spring-boot)

Comment: esas las he escrito yo en mi pom para cambiar las versiones que me dan vulnerabilidad en la página cuando subo la imagen

Comment: con esas dependencias deberías poder tener la clase `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired` ya que proviene del módulo `spring-beans`, mismo otros de los módulos importados tmb usan ese mismo. He probado crear un `hello word en spring` usando ese listado de dependencias y lo pude compilar sin problemas. Me llama la atención que la versión de `spring-core` quedó en `5.3.27` y el resto de módulos en `6.0.6` a excepción de `spring-security` que quedó en `6.0.1`. Así y todo pude ejecutarlo sin problema. No creo que el problema sea la versión de la JDK (spring 6 necesita `JDK 17+`)

Comment: Con los detalles provistos hasta ahora, no logro imaginar por dónde puede venir el error, a pesar de las cosas que marqué en el comentario anterior como la discrepancia de versiones entre los distintos módulos de spring. Este error te está dando en el IDE que estás usando o desde la línea de comandos?

Comment: Agrega más detalles del proyecto a nivel configuración, así como las herramientas que estás usando para ejcutarlo, qué comando utilizaste y el entorno sobre le que te encuentas trabajando (sistema operativo, máquina virtual, etc)

Comment: Estoy con windows 11, Java17, con IntellJ y el comando que he utilizado ha sido mvn clean install

Comment: Ya esta solucionado, no cambie la version de java en el pom principal que tambien habia que cambiarla y no me di cuenta. Un saludo y gracias!